# Objective C: Methods with return type of NSString but with variables inside

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a certain confusion on how to return values in Objective C with NSString return type but having variables inside it.

Is this okey?

```
- (NSString *)returnInfo{
    return @"Userinfo:\nusername: %@\npassword: %@", self.username, self.password;
}
```

Your answers are highly appreciated...
Thanks...

Comment: That's fine, if that's what you want to do.  There are several protocols for representing data in a character string -- XML, JSON, etc -- or you can "roll your own".  You have to decide what you want (or discern the requirements of some external interface you're matching).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should probably be

```
- (NSString *)returnInfo{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Userinfo:\nusername: %@\npassword: %@", self.username, self.password];
}
```

Your code would probably compile too, but it would return `password`, because of the way the comma operator works. This is almost certainly not what you had in mind, though.